# Create a report in Excel from a Master data using a pre-defined Template

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have bunch of data in a table called master list. I need to copy each and every row of data into a predefined template into separate excel files.

My master table is as below named as **Master.xls**. Please see

[image: Master table]

to see the master table format. I will keep adding data for this list in future. I have identified each column with color to describe where the data from each column will be copied to a **Pre-defined Template**

[image: Report Template].

This template should be created for each row of data in the table and saved as different files in my computer. The file must contain only one excel sheet named ***Report***. The name of the each file shall be ***SBR Report for "SBR#"***. This SBR# will be from [Master table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd432.png).

Comment: Can't you do that with simple lookup formulas? What is the question? Do you want us to write free code for you? Think again.

Comment: lookup formulas cannot create 100s of file in one shot. If done manually will take days. I would like to make it in short. I trying to find code myself as well. If found the answer I will update. Meanwhile I need help from others to get through this issue.

Comment: So, you are wanting us to write code for you for free? This won't work here. We will be happy to help with the code you have come up with so far, though. Please edit your question and post your code.